Merkle Tree vs Replication Log / Event Log
I understand that Merkle Trees can be used to replicate data and guarantee
integrity of the data in byzantine environment (where you don't trust all the parties) and that systems like cansandra use it to repair a node
without having to download the entire dataset like a traditional mysql replication.
Is there an advantage to use a Merkle tree instead of a traditional replication log if
you trust the other parties and corruption (read the size of the data) is not a concern?

Please describe exactly what you mean by using Merkle Tree for replacing traditional log replication. Log replication = cdc = stream of changes in the data. What do you wan to send instead? Please provide an example of database replication solution which uses alternate approach. You are giving as example not cdc but database repair scenario. Ok, but this is not cdc. Currently your question is that you are making a thesis that you want to use an algorithm for data integrity for cdc. Please provide exact details how you want to use it.

I'm not thinking about a specific data solution. I'm trying to understand if there would be an advantage to use merkle trees instead of a traditional stream of changes from a theoretical point of view.
In traditional stream of changes your read replica knows the replication offset and compares it with the master offset if they are different the replication resumes in order and every change is applied in order.
Merkle trees are obviously different also allow you understand what changed and replicate what changed. Just like a linear replication offset.

So you should rewrite you question. What you are asking actually is: I would like to use Merke Tree for enhancing log based replication. I have no idea how I can use it and no idea if this would actually help. Please propose ideas how I can utilise this algorithm for log replication.
